# Live FOREX data for PHP

Tags: php, currency

I am building an application where I need live FOREX(currency data). I could take it from yahoo's page, by loading the html into PHP and the get then extract the data. But I do not like doing that way. Therefore I would like to ask if any of you know any other free forex resources that can be loaded into PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YQL is good for harvesting web data: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and my solution was to run MetaTrader4 and write a tiny custom EA to HTTP GET the current o/h/l/c/b/a to a PHP script, which then dumps it into a MySQL database. Next step is to write some scripts to chart the data using PHPlot. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [European Central Bank](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/home/html/index.en.html) provides €-based exchange rates for [some foreign currencies](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html) as an easy to parse XML-document: http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml (there even is a PHP sample script available).

Answer (score 1):

Not free but may be worth looking at nevertheless: http://www.oanda.com/channels/business/business.shtml#data